PowerBi Data query times out after approx 10 minutes, with Oracle Error 01013
Users are querying data via on-premises PowerBI Data Gateway. Large data queries fail after approx 10 minutes with Oracle error 01013. Queries work fine if the data range is smaller.
Oracle Client for Microsoft Tools (64bit) v19.21 is installed on the same server as the On-premises data gateway v3000.230.13.
We have disabled timeouts on the ODBC connections on the Data Gateway server, and on users client machines, but the timeout still takes place. The data gateway is configured correctly and there are no gateway connectivity issues.
Is there a way to identify what's causing the timeout from the gateway logs? I do not know anything about Oracle but from online searches I gathered the issue may not be caused by the database.
In layman terms, is there a switch where we can disable the 10 minute timeout from?

01013 is "canceled by user request", are you sure there is no monitoring tool inside PowerBI killing long running request?

Thank you for your response. It appeared there was no tool killing the request inside PowerBI. This issue was fixed eventually by adding the CommandTimeout to the query in Power BI / Transform Data / Power Query Editor / Advance editor and modifying the M code to include the CommandTimeout parameter.
